# Datalife CMS file upload form not working pls

Tags: php, content-management-system, datalife-engine

I am DLE not uploading. My upload form no showing, chrome firebug:
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: url does not permit cross-origin framing.
Pls help me!
[image: DLE CMS]

Answer (score 0):

you must add below code in the top of **index.php** file of Datalife Engine:
`header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');`